# Java extends inheritance Program not working?

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans

So I have 3 files - And in on of the files it is giving me this error:

> Package in class Package cannot be applied to given types; required
>   int, char / Found no arguments

I've tried everything I can possibly think of and can't figure out how to fix it, it's probably a rookie error!? So I was hoping someone could help explain what I've done wrong. I will paste the code below!

## Package.java

```
package chap10q5;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class Package {
    int weight;
    char shippingMethod;
    double shippingcost;

public Package(int weight, char shippingMethod){
    this.weight = weight;
    this.shippingMethod = shippingMethod;

    if( (this.weight > 0 && this.weight <= 8) && this.shippingMethod == 'A'){
        this.shippingcost = 2.00;
    }
    else if( (this.weight > 0 && this.weight <= 8) && this.shippingMethod == 'T'){
        this.shippingcost = 1.50;
    }
    else if( (this.weight > 0 && this.weight <= 8) && this.shippingMethod == 'M'){
        this.shippingcost = 0.50;
    }

    if( (this.weight >=9 && this.weight <= 16) && this.shippingMethod == 'A'){
        this.shippingcost = 3.00;
    }
    else if( (this.weight >= 9 && this.weight <= 16) && this.shippingMethod == 'T'){
        this.shippingcost = 2.35;
    }
    else if( (this.weight >= 9 && this.weight <= 16) && this.shippingMethod == 'M'){
        this.shippingcost = 1.50;
    }

    if( (this.weight > 17) && this.shippingMethod == 'A'){
        this.shippingcost = 4.50;
    }
    else if( (this.weight > 17) && this.shippingMethod == 'T'){
        this.shippingcost = 3.25;
    }
    else if( (this.weight > 17) && this.shippingMethod == 'M'){
        this.shippingcost = 2.15;
    }

}

public String toString(){
    return "Weight: " + this.weight + "\nShipping Method: " + 
            this.shippingMethod + "\nCost: " + this.shippingcost;
}
}
```

## InsuredPackage.java

```
package chap10q5;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class InsuredPackage extends Package {

public InsuredPackage(int weight, char shippingCost){
    if(super.shippingcost <= 1){
        super.shippingcost += 2.45;
    }
    else if( (super.shippingcost > 1.00) && (super.shippingcost <= 3.00) ){
        super.shippingcost += 3.95;
    }
    else if( super.shippingcost > 3 ){
        super.shippingcost += 5.55;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return super.toString();
}
 }
```

## UsePackage.java (My main method):

```
package chap10q5;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class UsePackage {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Package one = new Package(1, 'A');

        System.out.println(one);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public InsuredPackage(int weight, char shippingCost){
    if(super.shippingcost <= 1){
        super.shippingcost += 2.45;
    }
    else if( (super.shippingcost > 1.00) && (super.shippingcost <= 3.00) ){
        super.shippingcost += 3.95;
    }
    else if( super.shippingcost > 3 ){
        super.shippingcost += 5.55;
    }
}
```

to

```
public InsuredPackage(int weight, char shippingMethod){
    super(weight,shippingMethod);
    if(shippingcost <= 1){
        shippingcost += 2.45;
    }
    else if( (shippingcost > 1.00) && (shippingcost <= 3.00) ){
        shippingcost += 3.95;
    }
    else if(shippingcost > 3 ){
        shippingcost += 5.55;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I figured it was something as easy as this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a default constructor in `Package`, you need to call one of `Package`'s constructors in your `InsuredPackage` constructor. For example:

```
public InsuredPackage(int weight, char shippingMethod, double shippingCost) {
    super(weight, shippingMethod);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thought it was something like this but I must've done it wrong earlier when I tried to do it. @Eran actually stated this above, so thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that when a constructor on a child class doesnt calls the constructor of the father class, the compiler puts on the first line a call to a default constructor, I mean `super()`, but you dont have defined that in your `Package` class, and that is the error.